# Does iconv with TRANSLIT work in Unix AIX?

Tags: iconv, transliteration

Does iconv with TRANSLIT work in Unix AIX ?Iit is not included in MANual.. I gave a try with this syntax and it did not work.

iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1//TRANSLIT File1 > File2

Answer (score 1):

Transliteration is a GNU iconv extension. Most unices do not support this extension, which is not in POSIX. You might have to compile GNU iconv to your platform to use this functionality.